# How to copy and release a buffer in Gstreamer

Tags: python, memory, buffer, gstreamer

I am working with the Python bindings for Gstreamer. I have a `Buffer` objects that I would like to copy and add to a queue so that it can be later processed by another thread.
My application has a memory leak but I am not sure whether this is related to Gstreamer.

**Copy the buffer**

Currently I am copying the buffer like this:

```
gst_buffer_copied = gst_buffer.copy_deep()
```

Is this correct?

**Release memory**

Do I need to release the resource explicitly later? How can I do that?
I tried with

```
gst_buffer_copied.remove_all_memory()
```

but I have `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` errors sometime. Not sure if that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gst_buffer_copied` buffer should take ownership of it's own memory. So when the lifetime of this buffer ends it will take care of releasing it's memory.

If you manually remove the memory chunks you should make sure no code in your application or pipeline is trying to access the buffer's memory after.

So when you do that but the pipeline has not yet finished processing this buffer it will try to access the memory you have just freed causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Ok so in brief, no action is required to delete the `gst_buffer_copied` right? The garbage collector will release it after there are no more references to it.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. In C code you would just explicitly release the buffer and it would destroy itself when the reference count hits 0. It then will delete its associated memory. In case of GC the GC should trigger the release.

Comment: Thanks! About the copy: do you think I am doing it correctly? I am working with Deepstream. If I access the copied buffer after a few seconds the data in the buffer is not the same. It seems that I am copying just a reference to the data and not the actual data.

Comment: It looks correct to me. The `deep` variant should copy the data without referencing it. Then again, we have no idea what you are doing with this buffer..

Comment: In my case I haven't solved the issue yet, but since you answered all my questions it seems right to select your post as the answer. Thanks!